# Does the same affliction stack?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

If you catch a specific affliction like a disease while in combat can you then catch it again next round?

What are the effects of this if it's possible?  Would you need to cure it twice? etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on the type of affliction - for diseases and curses, multiple exposures simply give multiple chances to contract the affliction. For poisons, the effects do stack, but possibly not the way you expect.

From the Poison subsection of the Afflictions section of the [Glossary](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/glossary.html) -

> Unlike other afflictions, multiple doses of the same poison stack. Poisons delivered by injury and contact cannot inflict more than one dose of poison at a time, but inhaled and ingested poisons can inflict multiple doses at once. Each additional dose extends the total duration of the poison (as noted under frequency) by half its total duration. In addition, each dose of poison increases the DC to resist the poison by +2. This increase is cumulative. Multiple doses do not alter the cure conditions of the poison, and meeting these conditions ends the affliction for all the doses. For example, a character is bit three times in the same round by a trio of Medium monstrous spiders, injecting him with three doses of Medium spider venom. The unfortunate character must make a DC 18 Fortitude save for the next 8 rounds. Fortunately, just one successful save cures the character of all three doses of the poison.

Comment: So you can't get multiple strengths of the same disease just because you were exposed to it (and failed the DC) multiple times.  e.g. you won't get Ghoul Fever x3 if you failed the DC against 3 Ghoul Fevers.